# Server Implementation for Push Notifications Sent Between Android and iPhone Devices

Tags: android, ios, node.js, push-notification

I would like to write an instant messaging mobile application with push notifications. One requirement is to have both an iPhone and Android version able to send push notifications between 2 devices regardless of the device type.

I am having trouble coming up with a best solution to send push notifications for the following 4 cases:

1. Android client -> server -> Android client.
2. Android client -> server -> iPhone client.
3. iPhone client  -> server -> iPhone client.
4. iPhone client  -> server -> Android client.

I have a few questions:

1. Did you find [pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd) simple to handle your push notifications? Did you run into any unforeseen issues?
2. What are the pros and cons between creating my own node.js server implementation and using [pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd) for the 4 cases above (minus learning more from doing it myself)?
3. Would it be simpler to use a different server implementation such as python or php through Apache?
4. Were there any resources you found to be critical to writing your own server implementation?
5. Is there a simpler suggestion for implementing push notifications between 2 cross-platform devices?

I've come across [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) and [Pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) but I don't think they apply to my use cases.

I apologize if this question seems to open-ended for SO but I have been struggling with this for the past few nights and am having a hard time coming up with these answers.

Thanks and I appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you had any luck trying with pushd? I'm also thinking to use it but it would be nice to know if someone has use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Parse.com
Its amazing, and their push notification service is much simplier than creating your own.

Comment: There is only problem I see with using a service like this; if a substantial userbase builds up, then their free service will not suffice and the pricing increases substantially from there.

Comment: Have you seen App42 for cross platform push? Their pricing jumps in smaller increments as opposed to Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an endpoint, gated to a database for your push notifications and post to that service w henever necessary. For clientside code, see [here for Android](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) and [here for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html). If you'd like server code, leave a comment and I'll post an edit to this answer,

Comment: I am more interested in the server code that would be able to handle receiving HTTP POST requests by sending out PUSH Notifications based on a lookup to a database for the the user device type. So, if an Android user sends a message to an iPhone user, the server will route the message to the correct PUSH notification service (APNS in this case).